# How to get discount in Laravel 5.8 project on apply coupon

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a coupon in my laravel project. I need to allow a discount on applying coupon click. but when I enter my code and click on an apply button it gives this message

> Trying to get property
>   `'{"id":1,"code":"ABC123","type":"fixed","value":30,"percent_off":null,"created_at":"2020-04-29 07:30:14","updated_at":"2020-04-29 08:34:21"}'` of non-object

Why I'm getting this error, please help me

**my model code is**

```
<?PHP

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Coupon extends Model
{

public static function findByCode($code)
{
    return self::where('code', $code)->first();
}

public function discount($total)
{
    if($this->type == 'fixed'){
        return $this->value;
    } elseif ($this->type == 'percent'){
        return ($this->percent_off / 100) * $total;
    } else{
        return 0;
    }
}
}
```

**controller code is**

```
<?PHP

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Coupon;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CouponsController extends Controller
{


/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $coupon = Coupon::where('code', $request->coupon_code)->first();

    if(!$coupon){
        return redirect('/checkout')->withErrors('Invalid coupon code. Please try again.');
    }

    session()->put('coupon', [
        'name' -> $coupon-code,
        'discount' -> $coupon->discount(User::amount()),
    ]);

    return redirect('/checkout')->with('success message', 'Coupon has been applied!');
}


/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
}
```

**my blade file is**

```
<div class="row">
<form action="{{ route('coupon.store') }}" method="POST">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
<label for="coupon">{{ __('I have Coupon') }}</label>
<input type="text" name="coupon_code" id="coupon_code">
<button type="submit">Apply</button>
 </div>    
 </form>
 </div>
```

**my database table is**

[Database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9JI9.png)

**my checkout page screen**

[Checkout page screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04KLG.png)

[image: error message screen]

**user model code**

```
<?PHP

namespace App;

use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var arra
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'phone', 'country', 'state', 'purpose', 'package', 'months', 'quantity', 'amount', 'expiry_date', 'last_login_at', 'last_login_ip',
];



/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];

public function videorecordings()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Videorecordings::class);
}
public function rearcameras()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Rearcameras::class);
}
public function calllog()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Calllog::class);
}
public function callrecordings()
{
    return $this->hashMany(Callrecordings::class);
}
public function messages()
{
    return $this->hashMany(Messages::class);
}
public function fbcallrecordings()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Fbcallrecordings::class);
}

}
```

Please help me to resolve this error and how to reduce the current amount by applying a coupon code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exactly where is this error message coming from? Is there a line number or file to narrow down the issue?

Comment: @aynber the exact error is coming from my controller code

Comment: `$coupon-code,` is a typo

Comment: @aynber sir I make changes $coupon-code to $coupon->code again I get the same error...please help me to resolve my this issue

Comment: 1) Not a sir, but thank you for the politeness. 2) Please provide the full error message with the line number and file. The error message is pretty vague and without that information, we're shooting in the dark.

Comment: Ohh sorry! , I attached my error screen message, please see...

Comment: Ah ha, now I see it. `'name' ->`, as well as the line below.  The `->` attempts to access an object variable. You need `=>` to set an array key/value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some typos in your controller method, please see below changes.

```
session()->put('coupon', [
   'name' => $coupon->code,
   'discount' => $coupon->discount(User::amount()),
]);
```

Comment: thanks for your but now I get this error Call to undefined method App\User::amount() please tell me how I resolve this issue and how I apply coupon on current amount

Comment: @AyushSrivastava method amount must be missing from your User model, I can not be sure without looking at the User model.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any method names amount in the User model...

Comment: Please try it like this ``User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first()->amount;``
The amount is a column in your user table not method so you have to use it like that.